# Unable to view SQL RS Services on Server or add new SQL Service Application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I have the following SharePoint 2010 Environment:

- 2 - WFE
- 3 - SharePoint Application Servers
- 1 - SharePoint Database
  Server with 2008R2

One of the Application Servers has SQL2012 SP1 installed with Reporting Services for SharePoint and the latest Reporting Services Add-In. Both WFEs also have the latest Reporting Services Add-In installed.

I have followed the instructions on sites like this: [Installing and Configuring SQL Reporting Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/biblog/archive/2012/12/04/installing-and-configuring-sql-reporting-services-on-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

I am able to run the following cmdlets from PowerShell:

```
Install-SPRSService 
Install-SPRSServiceProxy
get-spserviceinstance -all |where {$_.TypeName -like "SQL Server Reporting*"} | Start-SPServiceInstance
```

After completing the above steps I am unable to see **SQL Server Reporting Services Service** in the Services on Server within Central Administration nor am I able view SQL **Server Reporting Services Service Application** in Manage Service Applications.

What steps am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First instict, I have always installed the add-in on ALL sharepoint servers. Which server is Central Admin running on (assuming one of the application server) and make sure that server has the SSRS add-in installed.

On second thought; do you see the SSRS application in the drop down for "new" service application?

Comment: Central Admin is running on one of app servers, not the one with SQL2012. No, I do not see the SSRS in the "New" dropdown. I will try installing the Add-In on all App Servers.

Comment: Installing the SSRS Add-In on all Application Servers seems to have done the trick.